# WooCommerce Product Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-ecommerce

I planned to develop a wordpress eCommerce site by using woocommerce as my plugin.

I am trying to develop / implement a subscription type eCommerce site where user can purchase 1 year subscription and select product and save into product cart based on months.

For example, if customer wanted to purchase 1 year subscription box, he will need to add 12 items (with no duplicate item) into a cart, then he can checkout with the item.

I am currently looking at WooCommerce plugins but sadly there is no proper documentation written that there is this feature.

Can someone please help to guide me through what is the plugins and technologies I need to use?

Comment: There is no plugins for that, only custom development. As someone said "Think different"… As your yearly subscription plan (12 month) includes normally 12 different products (so may be one by month), which costs are (may be) included in that subscription plan… instead of adding to cart 12 different items with the subscription plan, Customer could just add the subscription plan, pay for it and then on his my account page, on a custom section he will be able to choose the different products. But this is mostly an advanced development... So Anyway you need to make it yourself or hire a developer.

Comment: Noted with Thanks Loic. I will study more and try to develop myself for this.
Still quite new to wordpress, so have to know what is the logic behind the development.

Thanks for the guide